# Custom permalinks for documents in Jekyll collections

Tags: jekyll

I want to add [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) to my Jekyll site. In my `_config.yml` file I set `output: true`:

```
collections:
  faq:
    output: true
```

In my source folder I added `_faq` folder and created a file named `1.md` in it.

When I generate the site I can see my document at `http://localhost:4000/faq/1.html`. But when I customize the permalink for this document and add `permalink: /faq/1` in its YAML front-matter, it doesn't display at `http://localhost:4000/faq/1` and downloads to the computer instead.

Is there any way to customize permalinks for documents in Jekyll collections (to show without .html extension)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permalink should be `permalink: /faq/1/`, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Permalink should be `permalink: /faq/:path/`

That will set the correct relative path for all files and subfolders of that collection and drop the `.html` suffix.